# Kendo grid foreign key Column in popup show as drop downlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

i have three tables tbl_admin_group ,tbl_admin_role, tbl_admin_groupRole the primary key of group and role are foreign keys in grouprole.
 now i have a form in which i want to display foreign keys in dropdownlist first 
for tbl_admin_role. image link given below
**Controller Action Method**

```
 public ActionResult GetGroupRole()
    {

        dbcontext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        List<TBL_ADMIN_GROUP_ROLE> lst = dbcontext.TBL_ADMIN_GROUP_ROLE.Where(x => x.IsDeleted == 0).ToList();
also try this
 //List<TBL_ADMIN_GROUP_ROLE> lst = dbcontext.TBL_ADMIN_GROUP_ROLE.Include(r => r.TBL_ADMIN_ROLE).Include(g => g.TBL_ADMIN_GROUP).ToList();
        ViewData["rolesList"] = lst;
        return View(lst);

    }
```

**Razor view**

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<TBL_ADMIN_GROUP_ROLE>().Name("Grid")

                .Columns(columns =>
                {
                    columns.Template(t => { }).Title("S.No").ClientTemplate("#= renderNumber(data) #");

                    columns.ForeignKey(p => p.RoleID, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["rolesList"], "RoleID", "RoleName")
                        .Title("Role").Width(200).EditorTemplateName("RolesDropDown");
                    columns.Bound(gp => gp.GroupID).Width(200).Title("Group ID");

                    columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); }).Title("Actions");
                })
                    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                        .Ajax()
                        .PageSize(10)
                        .Model(model => model.Id(gp => gp.GroupRoleID))
                                                                .Read(read => read.Action("GroupRole_Read", "Security"))
                        .Update(up => up.Action("UpdateGroupRole", "Security"))
                        .Destroy(update => update.Action("DeleteGroupRole", "Security")))
                        .Pageable(pageable => pageable
                                    .PageSizes(true)
                                    .ButtonCount(5))
                        .Selectable()
                        .Sortable()
                        .Editable(ed => ed.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).TemplateName("Update Group Role"))
                                  .Events(e => e.Edit("onEdit"))
                                          .Events(ev => ev.DataBound("resetRowNumber"))                                
            )
```

i also trying with editor template but failed. please help me . thank in advance.

**Editor Template**

```
 @model int
    @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m)
            .AutoBind(false)
            .OptionLabel("Select Role...")
            .DataTextField("RoleName")
            .DataValueField("RoleID")
            .DataSource(dataSource =>
            {
                dataSource.Read(read => read.Action("GetRoles", "Security"))
                        .ServerFiltering(true);
            })
    )
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6wMl.png)